# NO Data is load in Excel file using PHPExcel library

Tags: php, phpexcel

What I need:

1. on click of Export Tab Data from Database is loaded in  Excel file in format such as csv , xls etc..

My Problem :

- when Execute file  No Data is loaded in Excel File .

here is my code snippet :

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Cannot connect to database !');
    mysql_select_db("atesting_ess") or die('No database found in mysql !');

   if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

        /** Include PHPExcel */
     require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

         // Create your database query
       $query = "SELECT * FROM asana_tasks";  

       // Execute the database query
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

       // Instantiate a new PHPExcel object
       $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
      // Set the active Excel worksheet to sheet 0
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 

        $rowCount = 1; 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    //print_r($row);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['Projects_name'])
                ->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['Name']) 
                 ->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $row['Priority']); 

             $rowCount++; 
           } 
       // Redirect output to a client?s web browser (Excel2007)
     header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"'); 
     header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
     // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
     header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

1. i have tried t resolve the by adding dummy data its working Fine code:

   ```
      // Add some data
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
       ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
       ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
       ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
       ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');
   ```

   - its working fine.
   - here is header image url: http://postimg.org/image/ugjfcmoun/
   - i have used Php wrapper from https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: Any errors or warnings shown when you try to do this?

Comment: broswer shows 200k response code

Comment: have checked weather the data coming from the database correctly ?

Comment: yes  i do print_r it shows me  whole data

Comment: try to remove `headers()` and see what is it showing in the browser.

Comment: i have recieve data and response code is 200 k

Comment: When you say that you receive data after you've removed the headers, what exactly do you see? Is it readable, or just a stream of binary data?

Comment: Also, is your `some_excel_file.xlsx` being written correctly to the server?

Comment: no it is not  readable

Comment: If you use your browser diagnostic/developer tools, what headers does it show as actually being received by the browser?

Comment: i hve updated my haeder details with snpashot and updated my upadated my code .plaese tell where im wrong

Comment: im facing no download, nor load data in excel file.

Comment: So you're getting an empty workbook downloaded: are you absolutely certain that your database query is actually returning data

Comment: i have fix bug bug error reporting on  step1 off error reporting code.step 2. ob_start(); use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since column is A,B,C etc. and not 1,2,3, etc. convert it to a character. The code below works for columns A to Z, for AA,AB etc, this needs to be extended.

```
$columnvalue = strtoupper(chr($col) + 96));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columnvalue . $row, $value);
```

Comment: Or better yet, use the __built-in__ `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex()` method which can handle more than 26 columns

Comment: i recive error:Fatal error: Call to undefined function ucase() in simple-xlsx.php on line 34

Comment: i have post my updated code still nodata  so where im wrong ?$rowCount = 1; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
 //print_r($row);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['Projects_name']); 
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['Name']); 
  
    $rowCount++; 
}